# Azure Purview scan to SQL Managed Instance fails

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-purview

I followed this tutorial from Azure team: [Connect to and manage an `Azure SQL Managed Instance in Microsoft Purview](https://Connect%20to%20and%20manage%20an%20Azure%20SQL%20Managed%20Instance%20in%20Microsoft%20Purview). As shown in the image 1 below, the scan process successfully tested the connection. But later the scanning fails with the following error:

> > Error: (3860) Unable to access sql server with the specified connection parameters. Please ensure that the connection parameters can login to 'master' db to enumerate the other databases in the sql server.

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong, and can we resolve the issue?

**Remarks**: As shown in the image below, the database selected for scanning is `AdventureWorksLT2019`. In Purview, for Authentication, I am using [System Assigned Managed Identity (SAMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-sql-managed-instance#authentication-for-registration) that is the name `myPurview` of my purview account. And myPurview is a member of `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` in the database. Moreover, in the `New Login` window of SSMS (image 2 below), when I enter myPurview as as AAD account and click ok, the login window recognizes myPurview as a principal identity successfully add it as a login. I verified it by trying the same process by adding a fake name testPuview, and the same login dialog did not recognize it and threw the error `Principal testPuview could not be found or this principal type is not supported. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 33130)`.

After myPurview was successfully added as a login, I then added it to database with the read/write permissions. I also followed the [Configure public endpoint in Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/public-endpoint-configure?view=azuresql) article. So, I am not sure what may be causing the error

**Image 1**:

[image]

**Image 2**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Azure purview is failing to scan your Azure SQL managed Instance. A managed VNET IR needs to be created to have the managed private endpoints enabled. Please make sure to check if the option is grey out. Managed private endpoint requires you to set up managed vnet integration runtimes first and also requires data source admin roles. Please let me know if you need further assistance on this.

Comment: I am using `Public` endpoints and have followed this Azure doc: [Allow public endpoint traffic on the network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/public-endpoint-configure?view=azuresql#allow-public-endpoint-traffic-on-the-network-security-group). The issue may have something to do with item 4 of the article where we've selected `source`  as `IP Address` and then range of IP address is specified. We don't want to select source as `any` for security reasons. so, question would be which IP address (or ranges of IP address) to select?

Comment: What command you use to add Purview Managed Identity as Login in SQL MI and permission granted?